# Very basic question about category theory

Tags: ct.category-theory, symmetric-monoidal-categories

I have a symmetric monoidal category, and go to another one by replacing objects with isomorphism classes of objects. What's that called in category theory language?

To give an example, consider the symmetric monoidal category of finite-dimensional vector spaces (with tensor product). The isomorphism class of a vector space is given by it's dimension. So the objects of the new category would be given by non-negative integers. The morphisms between two numbers $a$ and $b$ would be given by linear maps between two canonical representatives $\mathbb{C}^a$ and $\mathbb{C}^b$.

Or, consider the category of finite sets (with functions and cartesian product). Again, the objects of the new category would be positive integers corresponding to the cardinality of the sets. The morphisms would be functions between canonical representatives $\{0,\ldots,a-1\}$ and $\{0,\ldots b-1\}$.

Does that operation make sense in category theory? And what's it called? I heard the term "strictification" and that sounds a bit like what the above operation is doing, but I didn't find any understandable explanation or examples for it.

Comment: This is called the skeleton. It is not the same as the strictification.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(category_theory)

Comment: (Note that this notion of "skeleton" is completely independent of the notion of $n$-skeleton for simplicial sets.)